# Serial port polling not working on Beaglebone Black

Tags: c++, linux, serial-port, beagleboneblack

I simply cannot get the poll() function to respond to data being sent over UART1 / /dev/ttyO1. Code as follows, maybe someone can spot my silly mistake?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/poll.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int openPort()
{
    struct termios oldtio, newtio;

    int fd = open("/dev/ttyO1",O_RDWR|O_NOCTTY|O_NONBLOCK|O_NDELAY);
    if (fd == -1)
    {
        printf( "could not open tty" );
        return -1;
    }

    if ( tcgetattr( fd, &oldtio ) == -1 )
    {
        printf( "error getting tcattr\n" );
        close( fd );
        return -1;
    }

    cfmakeraw( &newtio );
    cfsetispeed( &newtio, B9600 );
    cfsetospeed( &newtio, B9600 );
    newtio.c_cflag = (newtio.c_cflag & ~CSIZE) | CS8 | B9600;
    newtio.c_cflag |= (CLOCAL | CREAD);
    newtio.c_cflag &= ~(PARENB | PARODD);
    newtio.c_cflag &= ~CRTSCTS;
    newtio.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB;
    newtio.c_iflag = 0;//IGNPAR;
    //newtio.c_iflag &= ~(IXON | IXOFF | IXANY);
    newtio.c_lflag = 0;
    newtio.c_oflag = 0;
    newtio.c_cc[VTIME] = 0;
    newtio.c_cc[VMIN] = 1;
    tcflush( fd, TCIOFLUSH );
    if ( tcsetattr( fd, TCSANOW, &newtio ) == -1 )
    {
        close( fd );
        printf( "error setting attrs\n" );
        return -1;
    }

    return fd;
}

void selectLoop( int fd )
{
    struct pollfd fds[1];
    fds[0].fd = fd;
    fds[0].events = POLLIN;

    int rc = poll( fds, 1, 100000 );
    if (rc < 0)
    {
        perror( "poll" );
    }
    else if (rc > 0)
    {
        char buffer[32] = {0};
        int r = read( fd, buffer, sizeof(buffer) );
        if (r == -1)
        {
            printf( "error: %s\n", strerror( errno ) );
        }
        else
        {
            printf( buffer );
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf( "No data\n" );
    }
    //close( fd );
    sleep( 1 );
}

int main( int c, char ** v )
{
    int fd = openPort();
    if (fd >= 0)
    {
        while(1)
        {
            selectLoop(fd);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I get the same result using select(). However if I attach a signal to "data received" then the signal fires, though this is a scenario I am trying to avoid as it plays havoc with Netbeans' debug environment.

FYI: board revision is B6, UART1 is connected by TX/RX only. The "screen" program successfully receives and sends characters from the UART, so I know that it fundamentally works.

Comment: You forgot to tell us what the problem is. What result do you get? What do you expect?

Comment: I'm running a terminal (Hypertrm) on my dev PC, and typing characters into it. It's connected at 9600 baud, no parity, 1 stop bit, 8 bit chars, no h/w control. The "screen" program on my BBB echoes the characters I type, so I am hoping to see my program also echo the characters I type into my PC terminal. I get nothing - the poll() method just blocks, no errors, just does not see any input from the UART.

Comment: In openport(), newtio is used before it has been initialized.  You need something like `newtio = oldtio;` between the tcgetattr() and cfmakeraw().  Read [Setting Terminal Modes Properly](http://www.chemie.fu-berlin.de/chemnet/use/info/libc/libc_12.html#SEC237) and [Serial Programming Guide for POSIX Operating Systems](http://www.cmrr.umn.edu/~strupp/serial.html)

Comment: Good advice, @sawdust - but the result is identical. No echoed characters.

Comment: Right, we installed an FTDI cable through the hub on the BBB and opened a serial connection to that on /dev/ttyUSB0 - result was echoed characters! Hypothesis: the IO "data available" signal has not been set up (correctly) on /dev/ttyO1 - a kernel / cape / hardware bug?

Comment: However, the program now only prints every other character typed?

Comment: I replaced the "select" bit with a `while( read(...) > 0 ) {...}` and lo-and-behold I get correctly echoed strings. This seems to suggest that select() and poll() are broken under Angstrom Linux on BBB, so I would be really interested to hear if anyone has got them working!

Answer (score 0):

Replace this with something sensible:

```
        printf( buffer );
```

Perhaps:

```
for (int i = 0; i < r; ++i)
   putchar(buffer[i]);
fflush(stdout);
```

This flushes and doesn't risk printing more characters than read if the buffer is full.

Comment: Nice idea. Same result - nothing printed.

Comment: Did `poll` return? Maybe you're just receiving non-printable characters.

Comment: Didn't return, David.